# Debugging/Enabling Intel Display Audio on Intel HD Graphics 4000

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, intel-graphics, displayport

I'm working on an old Lenovo T430s with Intel HD Graphics 4000.  It has a mini display port, on which I'm using a miniDP-to-HDMI adapter.  I'm trying to get audio over this configuration.

I know the laptop used to work this way, as did the cable.  I know the monitor receives audio over HDMI.

The Intel Display Audio driver shows in Device Manager.  However, the Sound Control Panel doesn't list it as an audio device... it only lists the Realtek card.

Things I've tried:

- Fresh install of the latest drivers
- Different cables
- Different monitors
- Using the dock and its regular DisplayPort ports
- Configuring external monitor only and rebooting
- Testing in Ubuntu Desktop.  (Ubuntu works... just not Windows.)

Any thoughts on how I can resolve the situation, or at least debug what is happening?

Windows 10 x64

Comment: Do you see the device if you right-click the Volume icon in the traybar and select "Open Sound settings"?

Comment: @harrymc No, listed there is just the Realtek.

Comment: You could try to [reinstall Intel drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005656/graphics-drivers.html).

Comment: @harrymc I did.

Comment: Are you sure that the HD Graphics 4000 does produce sound? Or tried another port?

Comment: @harrymc Yes.  I used to use it in this configuration back when this machine ran Windows 8 years ago.  The laptop itself only has one mini-display port.  The docking station has 2 full-sized display ports and I've tried those as well.

Comment: Did the other ports produce sound?

Comment: @harrymc No, if they did I wouldn't be posting here.  :-)

Comment: Starting to think that the HD Graphics 4000 might be faulty. Last try: Delete it with its driver in the Device Manager and reboot so Windows installs its generic driver. This will likely lose your video, so you will need to shutdown via short press on the power button.

Comment: @harrymc I uninstalled the device from device manager, booted up in glorious 1024x768, but no external monitor can work in that way and naturally the Intel Display Audio device didn't show up.  A few minutes later, Windows re-installed the graphics drivers anyway.  Audio device still doesn't show up.

Comment: Hardware problem is the most likely. You did everything that's possible in software.

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately, not a hardware problem.  I tried booting into Ubuntu, and that's working.

Comment: @harrymc Here's a good one... after rebooting back to Windows, it works!  If I fully shut down and reboot into Windows... it doesn't work.  Something about the Ubuntu driver is leaving something in a state where the Windows drivers work.

Comment: Try rebooting into Windows after a successful boot into Windows. Try also boot after shutdown (cold boot).